# Bubble sort query

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I don't understand what is happening on line 2, with the "-1, 0 , -1". Why does it need to do this, and what does the zero represent?

I have run the code, when I removed the "-1, 0, -1" part and it didn't sort the list. I don't understand why it is such a crucial part of code

```
def bubbleSort(alist):
    for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1): #line 2
        for i in range(passnum):
            if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                temp = alist[i]
                alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                alist[i+1] = temp

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
bubbleSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

Comment: It may be helpful to refer to the [documentation for `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to determine the meaning of its second and third arguments.

Comment: I did, but I don't understand it properly.

Comment: Imagine len(alist)=5. It set `passnum` to 4, 3, 2 and 1. Zero is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

That has nothing to do with the algorithm. `range` has 3 arguments

- from
- to
- step

In this case, this means

- start from the last element (index=N-1)
- continue until the second (index=0)
- step=-1 (to go backwards)

Comment: Not penultimate

Comment: Starts from the _last_ element, and stops _before_ the one at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Those are arguments to `range(start, stop, sep)`  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
In your case you create a range that starts with the length of your list -1 (`len(alist)-1`), and count to 0, by taking steps of -1.

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggest, if you'd googled the docs for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), you might have worked things out. Your line:

```
range(len(alist)-1,0,-1)
```

Means the range starts at the **end** of the list (which is the length, minus 1, since lists are [0 indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)), and ends at **1** (one before 0), with steps of **-1** (backwards).